# How to use datacamp's tutorial package to insert R exercises in xaringan slides?

Tags: r, xaringan

I recently came across [DataCamp's tutorial package](https://github.com/datacamp/tutorial) that makes code chunks within an R Markdown document interactive by opening the code chunks in DataCamp's learning interface. I used `tutorial::build_example()` to generate an example file and compiled it to see how the rendered html file looks. It works as expected. Since I wanted to use this feature in `xaringan` slides, I changed `output: html_document` to `output: xaringan::moon_reader` and now I see this:

[image]

I am wondering why this is failing in `xaringan` slides and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tutorial` is meant to work for the `html_document` format of rmarkdown which behaves differently than xaringan. I think it's not worth the hassle to go the detour and try to get it working via the `tutorial` package.

Ultimately, you just need to write some HTML and embed [datacamp-light.js](https://github.com/datacamp/datacamp-light):

Set up an HTML file which includes the JS

**dc.html**

```html
<script async='async' src='https://cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz'></script>
```

and include it in the YAML header of your xaringan project:

**.Rmd**

```yaml
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["customtheme.css"]
    includes:
      in_header: "dc.html"
```

You may then write interactive exercises using the same SCTs etc. but using HTML chunks:

```html
---
## DC

<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang='r' data-height = 320>
<code data-type="sample-code">
 set.seed(123)
 # draw the winning numbers for this week
</code>
<code data-type="solution">
 set.seed(123)
 # draw the winning numbers for this week
 sample(1:49, size = 6)
</code>
<code data-type="sct">
 test_function("sample", args = c("x","size"))
</code>
</div>
```

[image]

Note that typing code will interfere with xaringan keyboard shortcuts so you want to disable them.